# How to change data using change event in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

How to change data while using with (change) event. I am trying to change the gallery items by matching value, default I want to show all gallery items

```js
public items = [{
    value: 'All',
    name: 'All Items'
  },
  {
    value: 'Photos',
    name: 'Photo Items'
  },
  {
    value: 'Video',
    name: 'Video Items'
  },
];
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items" class="nav-li">
  <ul>
    <li class="value" [value]="item.value"><a href="">{{item.value}}</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items" class="card">
    <div class="data">{{item.name}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ant to show All items if click on the Photos change to show photos data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfdatt) this is html with pipe

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | customPipe : filter" class="card">
    <div class="data">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

in component create filter value as initial 'All'

```
filter='All'
```

in list give click method for each li

```
<ul>
   <li class="value"(click)="onChange(item.value)" [value]="item.value"><a href="">{{item.value}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

in component

```
onChange(value){
  this.filter=value;
}
```

this is pipe example

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'customPipe'
})

export class CustomPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(row: any[],filter:string): any {
      return row.filter(x=>filter=='All' || x.value==filter);       
  }
}
```